# Why golang go-gin error always returning empty object

Tags: go, go-gin

im trying to parse error validation in gin golang, but produce an empty object "{}"

Here is my 1st attempt :

```
resp, err := userService.UserRegistrationService(c)

if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err})
    return
}
```

returning :

```
{
    "error": [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

Here is my 2nd attempt :

```
resp, err := userService.UserRegistrationService(c)

if err != nil {
    dada := fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, dada)
    return
}
```

returning

```
{}
```

Take a look if I debug the err parameter :

```
resp, err := userService.UserRegistrationService(c)
    fmt.Println(err)
    if err != nil {
        dada := fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
        fmt.Println(dada)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, dada)
        return
    }
```

Its return :

```
2020/11/10 12:41:46 stdout: Key: 'User.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag
2020/11/10 12:41:46 stdout: Key: 'User.Password' Error:Field validation for 'Password' failed on the 'required' tag
```

Can you guys help me, trying to search anywhere still no luck, I want return like this :

```
{
    "MyRequestStruct.PropertyOne": {
        "FieldNamespace": "MyRequestStruct.PropertyOne",
        "NameNamespace": "PropertyOne",
        "Field": "PropertyOne",
        "Name": "PropertyOne",
        "Tag": "required",
        "ActualTag": "required",
        "Kind": 24,
        "Type": {},
        "Param": "",
        "Value": ""
    },
    "MyRequestStruct.PropertyTwo": {
        "FieldNamespace": "MyRequestStruct.PropertyTwo",
        "NameNamespace": "PropertyTwo",
        "Field": "PropertyTwo",
        "Name": "PropertyTwo",
        "Tag": "required",
        "ActualTag": "required",
        "Kind": 24,
        "Type": {},
        "Param": "",
        "Value": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `err.Error()` instead of `err` while publishing as `json` response.

Try this :

```golang
resp, err := userService.UserRegistrationService(c)

if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
}
```

Comment: no, err.Error() will return string : ```{
    "error": "Key: 'User.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag\nKey: 'User.Password' Error:Field validation for 'Password' failed on the 'required' tag"
}```

Comment: I think the fields of the `err` you used, are not `exported`. That's why there's nothing in the response body. Can you check the `err` structure you used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

how to use it without an empty return?

```
resp, err := userService.UserRegistrationService(c)

if err != nil {
  c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
    "error": err.Error()
  })

  return

}
```